# How to find and compare all the keyword of a same type in a string

Tags: java

I want to write a method in java to parse a string which is a condition phrase and compare if there is at least one space before and after ALL the logical keyword. for example:

```
String condition1 = "S(GLHOLD) AND S(GLSHOVE) OR S(PLINK) OR S(PSHARE) AND S(PSTT) AND S(PNET)"          
String condition2 = "S(GLHOLD) AND S(GLSHOVE) OR S(PLINK)OR S(PSHARE) AND S(PSTT) AND S(PNET)"       
String condition3 = "S(GLHOLD) ANDS(GLSHOVE) OR S(PLINK) OR S(PSHARE) AND S(PSTT) AND S(PNET)"
```

Here condition1 is good but 2 and 3 are not since they have missing space. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a list of valid commands/keywords in a list somewhere?

Comment: Use regular expressions to test for this.

Comment: As a starting point, try [String.split()](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html)?

Comment: A simple ANTLR parser could do this too.

Comment: For clarification, what do you want your method to do with contition2 and condition3?  Do you want it to throw an IllegalArgumentException?  Or just return a boolean false?  Or did you want to return an array of Strings?  I'm not sure if you're trying to parse the String or just see if it's logically parsable.

Comment: What about "S(PNET) OR S(MORE)"? And is "S(PNET) S(PSTT)" valid, or must they be separated by a keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex, this works:

```
public static boolean containsSeparated(String condition, List<String> keywords) {
    for (String word : keywords) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S" + word + "|" + word + "\\S");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(condition);
        boolean foundNotSeparated = matcher.find();
        if (foundNotSeparated) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`\S` is not-whitespace, so exactly what you need to find to mark input as invalid, and it should be searched in both begin and end of given word

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String condition1 = "S(GLHOLD) AND S(GLSHOVE) OR S(PLINK) OR S(PSHARE) AND S(PSTT) AND S(PNET)";
    String condition2 = "S(GLHOLD) AND S(GLSHOVE) OR S(PLINK)OR S(PSHARE) AND S(PSTT) AND S(PNET)";
    String condition3 = "S(GLHOLD) ANDS(GLSHOVE) OR S(PLINK) OR S(PSHARE) AND S(PSTT) AND S(PNET)";

    List<String> shuoldBeSeparated = Arrays.asList("OR", "AND");
    System.out.println(containsSeparated(condition1, shuoldBeSeparated));
    System.out.println(containsSeparated(condition2, shuoldBeSeparated));
    System.out.println(containsSeparated(condition3, shuoldBeSeparated));
    System.out.println(containsSeparated("A AND B ORCC", shuoldBeSeparated));
    System.out.println(containsSeparated("A AND D", shuoldBeSeparated));
    System.out.println(containsSeparated("A AND B OR C", shuoldBeSeparated));
}

public static boolean containsSeparated(String condition, List<String> keywords) {
    for (String word : keywords) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S" + word + "|" + word + "\\S");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(condition);
        boolean foundNotSeparated = matcher.find();
        if (foundNotSeparated) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

prints:

1. true
2. false
3. false
4. false
5. true
6. true

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for "condition is ok" or not, then it's just this code:

```
private static boolean spacesEverywhere(String condition) {
    return !condition.toUpperCase().matches(".*((AND|OR)\\S+|\\S+(AND|OR)).*");
}
```

The regular expression searches for AND, OR with non-whitespace before or behind it (or both).

Additionally:

1. If you want to know, at which position the missing space is, I would split with "(AND|OR)" as regular expression and check each string in the resulitng array if it starts or end with a non-whitespace character.
2. If the condition itself could contain AND or OR, like such a condition: `"S(GLH**OR**D) AND S(GLSHOVE)"` then I would try ANTLR

Comment: have you tested it? ;)

Comment: Actually yes :-) With the three conditions in the question and an empty string. Result was false, true, true, false (for empty)

Comment: @jobi inddeed, but 1 is ok, 2 and 3 are not ok. And yours method name suggest that results should be: true, false, false. :) IMO You need to add negation on the begining.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will be similar to this:

```
private static boolean isValid(final String condition)
{
    String[] splitValues = condition.split("AND|OR");

    if (!splitValues[0].endsWith(" "))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (!splitValues[(splitValues.length - 1)].startsWith(" "))
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int index = 1; index < (splitValues.length - 1); ++index)
    {
        if (!splitValues[index].startsWith(" "))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!splitValues[index].endsWith(" "))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Split the string using AND and OR as the seperators.  between every string and every seperator, there must be at least one space character or the string is formatted incorrectly.

Comment: Wouldn't splitting on " AND | OR " be easier?

Comment: I want to print error in each case, I took out the boolean and put my print error instead of return but got wierd result.sorry I am novice to java.

Comment: @user2766131 how can you get wierd result if this method is fully valid?

Comment: use the boolean.  when the method returns false, the condition is an error.  print the error at that time.